# Placing/Overlapping(z-index) in android

Tags: android, z-index, overlapping

I want to make layout as the first screenshot.
[image: need]
<sub>(source: [nocookie.net](https://images1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20090901163013/uncyclopedia/images/e/eb/Blank.jpg))</sub>

I tried to do, but it turned out as in the second screenshot
[image: have]
<sub>(source: [nocookie.net](https://images1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20090901163013/uncyclopedia/images/e/eb/Blank.jpg))</sub>

Here my layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:gravity="center" 
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:padding="20dip" > 
 
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="0dip" 
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:background="@color/red" 
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:paddingBottom="40dip" 
        android:paddingLeft="10dip" 
        android:paddingRight="10dip" 
        android:paddingTop="10dip" > 
 
        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:background="@color/black" 
            android:gravity="center_vertical" > 
 
            <ScrollView 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_marginLeft="-20dip"  > 
 
                <TextView 
                    android:id="@+id/textView1" 
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    android:layout_gravity="center" 
                    android:gravity="center" 
                    android:text="lololo"  /> 
            </ScrollView> 
 
            <ImageView 
                android:id="@+id/lady" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:src="@drawable/temp" /> 
        </LinearLayout> 
    </LinearLayout> 
 
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_marginTop="-20dip" 
        android:gravity="center" > 
 
 
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/button1" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:background="@drawable/button_left" 
            android:text="next" /> 
 
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/button2" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:background="@drawable/button_right" 
            android:text="prev" /> 
    </LinearLayout> 
 
</LinearLayout>
```

I want to know how can we place one view above the other, with varying z-index?
I want to know how can we place one view above the other, with varying z-index?
I want to know how can we place one view above the other, with varying z-index?

Comment: Have you tried to change the parent of ScrollView and ImageView from LinearLayout to FrameLayout

Comment: Yes, but it did not help

Comment: I dont think that z order will help you if you look your layout then i think what you have done is that you have created textview in your inner linear layout now if you set z order then it will make it front with other sibling but I dont think you want that.. I think you want to allow your textview to cross linear layout or its parent... I think fisrt you should change everything in relative layout then it will work fine with some dummy view and settlements.

Comment: Never edit your question to remove all content. If you've found a solution, post it as an answer.

Comment: Your images are all white--can you fix them?

Answer (score 2):

Use `RelativeLayout`.

You can use this example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <!-- Bottom layer -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:background="#DDDDDD" >

            <!-- Other views -->
        </LinearLayout>

        <!-- Top layer -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="#F0AB00" >

            <!-- Other views -->
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And it looks like this:

[image]

As you can see in the picture, the small rectangle is located above the big (gray) rectangle. This can happen by adding views into RelativeLayout one after another (without referencing between them).

Regards

Comment: I know about the relative layout, but it does not solve the problem.

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to achieve exactly? Means, what is the purpose of the ScrollView? Should the 'lololo' text and image be static on the screen or should it be within the scrollable view?

Answer (score 1):

use the RelativeLayour and redesign  your layout....

you will get perfect result as you want..

RelativeLayour allow you to so stuff like this easily...

Comment: I tried to use the relative layout, but the necessary result was not achieved. Can more detail?